# What is the simplest way to program a minimal 'file ticket' web app?

Tags: php, python, node.js

Trying to find the right terms to describe this (searched on StackExchange and Google): can't believe something like this doesn't exist already.

Individual users log on to a (minimal) website via web browser by typing their individual ID code (fixed length). They are then prompted to download one file, randomly chosen by the server from a set held in a directory on the server. The user's ID and the name of the file they were allocated is stored on the server (flat-file and human-readable ideally), and if a user logs in with the same ID more than once they get exactly the same file. It should be possible to either have the list of IDs pre-populated, or to be dynamically created as users log in for the first time.

And no, this isn't a programming assignment. I'm on the other side - a teacher who needs to distribute files containing problems to students, making sure that each student gets a different file. There must be a nice short way to do this in PHP, Node.JS or a Python web framework that can be frozen (ideally) into a single portable Windows .EXE (i.e. server and app together).

Suggestions welcomed (including search terms that might take me closer to a solution)!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get deterministic randomness is to seed the random number generator by the `user_id`.

```
$user_id = 25;
$assignment_id = 4;
$nr_of_different_files = 5;

srand($user_id + $assignment_id * 1000);
$file_index = rand(0, $nr_of_different_files);
```

This way you don't need to store who gets which file. Keep in mind though that if any of the parameters change the random outcome will also change.

---

As for:

> There must be a [..] way to do this [..] that can be frozen (ideally) into a single portable Windows .EXE (i.e. server and app together).

This part is much too broad to answer here. Conicidentally, PHP, Python and JavaScript are all interpreted languages. They are never compiled into executables. You probably can but you're well off the beaten track.

Comment: Thanks Frits. I know PHP and Node.JS aren't (usually) compiled, but Python programs can be (via cx_freeze etc.)